# If $i$ is an inclusion map, is this equality: $\int_C i^*(\alpha) = \int_M \alpha$ correct?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact oriented manifold and let $C$ be a submanifold of $M$. We denote by $i : C \rightarrow M$ the inclusion map of $C$ into $M$ and by $i^*$ the pullback of $i$.

Let $\alpha $ be a smooth differential form on . Does this following equality hold

$$ \int_C i^*(\alpha) = \int_M \alpha .$$

Thank you!

Comment: What about volume forms, wouldn't they integrate to the volume of the respective manifolds, hence not be equal (as long as the manifolds have different volumes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, the integral of a form is only nonzero for forms of dimension equal to that of the manifold. For instance, when we integrate (compactly supported) $n-$forms $\omega$ on an $n-$manifold $M$. If you take a submanifold $N$ of $M$ of dimension $k<n$, included by $i:N\to M$, then $i^*\omega$ is an $n-$form on $N$. So, the integral is zero by convention.

In particular, if $\int_M\omega\ne 0$, then $\int_N i^*\omega\ne \int_M \omega$ in this case.

Comment: thank you so much !